# What is the gap between average values in a Gaussian Process and the real mean values?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, convergence-divergence, machine-learning, gaussian

Let's consider a function $f(x)$ where $x \in \mathcal X$, and $f(x)$ is sampled from a Gaussian Process. Also assume that for each $x\in\mathcal X$, $f(x)$ has a fixed unknown mean which is $\mu(x)$.

Question: Can we say anything about the relationship between $\mu_t(x)$ and $\mu(x)$? I mean is there any interval around $\mu_t(x)$ (for example $[\mu_t(x) - \alpha\sigma_t(x),\mu_t(x) + \alpha\sigma_t(x)]$) such that $\mu(x)$ lies in  it with high probability?

Edit: $t$ is indicating the iterations here, i.e. at time $t$ after getting a sample from $f$ we update all the means and variances (having a special kernel), and same for $t+1$ and so on.

Comment: It is unclear to me how $\mu$ is a function of both $x$ and $t$?

Comment: For each $x\in \mathcal X$ there is a $\mu(x)$, for which $\mu_t(x)$ converges to it.

Comment: I still cannot understand it in the framework of a stochastic process. Let's assume $N_t$ is the Gaussian process, where $t\in\mathcal{T}$ represents time, and for each instance $t_0$, $N_{t_0}$ is a sample; a random variable with mean $\mu_{t_0}$. What does $\mathcal{X}$ represent? What is the role of $x$?

Comment: $f(x)$ sampled from a GP: a collection of random variables, one for each $x\in \mathcal X$. Every finite subset of which is multivariate Gaussian distributed in an overall consistent way. Check https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-540-28650-9_4

Comment: Oh... In my experience, proceed with caution when it comes to probability in ML textbooks.